# Find a lower bound using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $B$ a square positive definite matrix. Define
$$\mu=\frac{(y^TB^{-1}y)(s^TBs)}{(y^Ts)^2}$$
How can I prove that $\mu\ge 1$? So far I get
$$\frac{(y^TB^{-1}y)(s^TBs)}{(y^Ts)^2}\ge \frac{(y^TB^{-1}y)(s^TBs)}{\lVert y \rVert^2\lVert s \rVert^2},$$
but, how can I use C-S inequality in the numerator to get the desired bound? I was thinking in the fact that $y^TB^{-1}y\ge -\lVert y\rVert \lVert B^{-1}y\rVert$ and the same for $s^TBs$, but I cannot see anything else. Even if I use the positivity of $B$, I get
$$ (y^TB^{-1}y)(s^TBs)\ge -\lVert y\rVert \lVert B^{-1}y\rVert (s^TBs),$$
but I do not see any useful expression. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y^\top s = y^\top B^{-1/2} B^{1/2} s = (B^{-1/2} y)^\top (B^{1/2} s).$$
Now apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure how I can use this decomposition of B in the expression $\mu$. Should I factorice $B$ and $B^{-1}$ in the numerator of $\mu$?And if I use the CS inequality, what can I do with the square roots of B?

Comment: When you apply the CS inequality you can bound the right-hand side by $\|B^{-1/2} y\| \|B^{1/2} s\|$. Then note that $\|B^{1/2} s\| = \sqrt{s^\top B s}$, and so on.